# Audio call's ICE failed after getting Video Call connected in Same Activity in Android using WebRTC and JanusGateway

Tags: android, audio, video, webrtc, janus-gateway

I am getting a Video Stream including audio and a separate Audio Stream. Both from same server.

I started with video stream and connected the call on one screen - Working fine.

Then worked with Audio Stream to connect call on another screen - Worked fine.

Now when i try to merge them into one screen.

Add Video call and audio call on same screen.

Video call is working but Audio call tries to connect then ICE failed and audio call got hangup.

Separately Video call and audio call both are working. But when i add them to one screen. Here they mess up with Audio call which is calling after video call connected.

i am using two sets of the different Signalling process (SDP, ICE, etc) to connect to 2 steams from a same server as peer.

Where i am wrong?